# Renaming Docker Volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run:

```bash
docker compose -f /docker-compose.yaml up
```

I get:

```
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠿ Volume "_mongo-data"  Error                                                                     0.0s
Error response from daemon: create _mongo-data: "_mongo-data" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

Here is the compose.yaml file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  my-app:
    image: ${docker-registry}/my-app:1.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver:local
```

Comment: Do you possibly have the environment variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` set, but to an empty string; or similarly in a `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve with the volume.
Docker (and Docker compose) have a concept of named/unnamed volumes and bind mounts. The differences are described in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose)

In case you want to just add a folder from your current working directory you can solve this by doing what the error message is telling you, adding the path using an absolute path directly in the service definition:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    volumes:
       - /home/user/myproject/mongo-data:/data/db
```

or by chaning the volume configuration on the bottom using the "long syntax" to:

```
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /home/user/myproject/mongo-data
```

Then you'll could use the named volume like this:

```
...
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data.db
...
```

in the service.

Answer (score 0):

```
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver:local
```

Notice that a space required between driver and local

correct way:

```
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```